# Java Swing - ScheduledExecutor Service Stops working upon UserInput

Tags: java, swing, scheduledexecutorservice

I am building a Maze where Monster is tracking the player and moving towards it. I have a function called SwapCells where I believe the problem lays in. SwapCells is used to move both Monster and Player. I have a ScheduledExecutorService that runs Monstermover which uses SwapCells. The Monster starts moving when the game starts, now the problems is when I start moving the player, the ScheduledExecutorService stops working and I can only move the player. I believe the problem is that, unlike MoveMonster, the Keylistener is not part of ScheduledExecutorService, hence when I invoke KeyListener that in turn runs SwapCell, it makes the ScheduledExecutorService stop. Any advice? Please Help!

```
private final int CELLSIZE = 20;
private ArrayList<Level> levels = new ArrayList<Level>();
private Player player;
private Monster monster;
private DisplayInfo display;        
private int xSize;
private int ySize;
private int currentLevel = 0;
private int direction = 0;
//private CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(15);

public Game(int xSize, int ySize) {
    player = new Player(0,0);
    monster = new Monster(0,1);
    setXSize(xSize);
    setYSize(ySize);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(ySize, xSize));
    addLevel();
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {                  

        // POSSIBLE PROBLEM IS HERE !!
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

                if(!hitWall) }  
                swapCells(getCurrentLevel().getMap()[x+dx][y+dy], getCurrentLevel().getMap()[x][y], player);
            }
            }
        }
    });     

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> moveMonster(), 0L, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);        

}                                            

public void swapCells(Cell cell1, Cell cell2, Mover mover) {
    Icon tempIcon = cell1.getLabel().getIcon();
    String tempID = cell1.getID();

    // sets mover's x and y value
    mover.setX(cell1.getX());
    mover.setY(cell1.getY());       

    // sets mover's cell to new cell
    getCurrentLevel().getpMaze().setCell(cell1, mover);

    getCurrentLevel().getMap()[cell1.getX()][cell1.getY()].setID(cell2.getID());
    getCurrentLevel().getMap()[cell1.getX()][cell1.getY()].getLabel().setIcon(cell2.getLabel().getIcon());
    getCurrentLevel().getMap()[cell2.getX()][cell2.getY()].setID(tempID);
    getCurrentLevel().getMap()[cell2.getX()][cell2.getY()].getLabel().setIcon(tempIcon);        
}

public void moveMonster() { 

    PerfectMaze currentMaze = getCurrentLevel().getpMaze();
    ArrayList<Cell> trackToPlayer = currentMaze.getTrack(currentMaze.getMonsterCell(), currentMaze.getPlayerCell(), "P");
    Collections.reverse(trackToPlayer);
    Cell nextCell = trackToPlayer.get(1);   
    //swapCells(nextCell, currentMaze.getMonsterCell(), monster);
    swapCells(getCurrentLevel().getMap()[nextCell.getX()][nextCell.getY()], getCurrentLevel().getMap()[monster.getX()][monster.getY()], monster);       

}
```

Comment: Post [mre] please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only interact with Swing components from the Swing "Event Dispatch Thread" (EDT). But you created an `ExecutorService`, and its threads are manipulating Swing components directly.

Instead, perform your background work in a [`SwingWorker`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) which can pass graphical updates safely to the EDT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With Swingworker, I am able to Move the Player while Monster mover works in the Backround in Scheduled 1second to move the Monster towards the Player. You said not to use ExecutorService, but I need to call MonsterMover() every 1 second. I am not aware if there is any other better way of doing this. 
I am still having some kind of bug in my code, but at least MonsterMover() is being called.